# What is the nicest way to parse this in C++?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, boost, stl

In my program, I have a list of "server address" in the following format:

```
host[:port]
```

The brackets here, indicate that the `port` is optional.

- `host` can be a hostname, an IPv4 or IPv6 address (possibly in "bracket-enclosed" notation).
- `port`, if present can be a numeric port number or a service string (like: "http" or "ssh").

If `port` is present and `host` is an IPv6 address, `host` **must** be in "bracket-enclosed" notation (Example: `[::1]`)

Here are some valid examples:

```
localhost
localhost:11211
127.0.0.1:http
[::1]:11211
::1
[::1]
```

And an invalid example:

```
::1:80 // Invalid: Is this the IPv6 address ::1:80 and a default port, or the IPv6 address ::1 and the port 80 ?
::1:http // This is not ambigous, but for simplicity sake, let's consider this is forbidden as well.
```

My goal is to separate such entries in two parts (obviously `host` and `port`). I don't care if either the `host` or `port` are invalid as long as they don't contain a non-bracket-enclosed `:` (`290.234.34.34.5` is ok for `host`, it will be rejected in the next process); I just want to separate the two parts, or if there is no `port` part, to *know* it somehow.

I tried to do something with `std::stringstream` but everything I come up to seems hacky and not really elegant.

How would you do this in `C++` ?

I don't mind answers in `C` but `C++` is prefered. Any `boost` solution is welcome as well.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "pick". I designed the format myself (if that's what you're asking) but I believe it is a very common one. I could have used another separator, but I don't think it would have been elegant. Example: "Connecting to localhost$http" seems is less intuitive than "Connecting to localhost:http".

Comment: If you don't want to change the separator (localhost-http seems fine to me though) then you could force all hosts to be bracket enclosed, otherwise regex would do it

Comment: `-` is a legitimate character for hostnames; I don't really want to replace on ambiguity by another ;)

Comment: Good question, I'm thinking the same task in C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at [boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/warming_up.html)? It might be overkill for your task, though.

Comment: Didn't know it existed. Thanks. However, as you just said, seems kind of overkill for my task. I no one else comes up with something more straightforward, I'll surely take a deep look into it.

Comment: Since the community seems to love this solution, could someone please give me a few guidelines to get started with `boost::spirit` in my specific case ?

Comment: @ereOn: Unfortunately, I never had a reason to work with spirit and it never made it to the top of my list of things I would like to play with either, so I cannot give you any advice. AFAIK it's a big and heavy template-meta machinery and might well be overweight for your purpose. Wouldn't regex help here? If not, I'd probably just write a simple parser using string streams. That said, the way that spirit tutorial starts out seems sooo interesting...

Comment: @Matthieu: I'm afraid that one went over my head. What's the [__towel__](http://walnuss.cms.hu-berlin.de/pub/index.php/London/DSC01604.JPG?action=big&size=resize) for?

Comment: Don't you know h2g2 ? You should always have a towel with you.

Comment: @sbi: Urbandictionary defines "Don't forget to bring a towel" as an amazing thing to randomly say.  May 25 was towel day in honor of  Douglas Adams.

Comment: @Matthieu & @Brian: I am well aware of the root of that phrase (see the link in my comment), I just don't know how to apply it here. It was probably stupid of me to expect a reasonable cause...

Comment: Oh, that's just because `ereOn` asked for guidelines to get started with boost::spirit and I remembered my first chaotic tries. It takes a bit to get beyond the `"Hello, world!"` (at least it took a bit for me). You really need to leverage a number of boost libraries to get past the most trivial examples: Phoenix to express the functors, Variant whenever you get unrelated types in a collection, etc... and I spare you the grievous error messages when something is off... I admire the power/cleverness nonetheless :)

Comment: You never told me about this, @sbi :) Added my take in X3. It does deal with the "ambiguous" cases gracefully as well. And throws in validation / DNS resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66827620/85371

Comment: @sehe: I am not sure you were even already around in the chat when I wrote this answer. I certainly didn't yet know how badly you are nerding out on Spirit back then. `:)`

Comment: @sbi You're absolutely right. The way I remember I started -using- my SO account ~2011, and probably only stepped into the lounge in 2012 or so

Comment: @sehe: FWIW, I have long since upvoted all answers towards Spirit which go into more detail than mine, including yours.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple class that uses boost::xpressive to do the job of verifying the type of IP address and then you can parse the rest to get the results.

Usage:

```
const std::string ip_address_str = "127.0.0.1:3282";
IpAddress ip_address = IpAddress::Parse(ip_address_str);
std::cout<<"Input String: "<<ip_address_str<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Address Type: "<<IpAddress::TypeToString(ip_address.getType())<<std::endl;
if (ip_address.getType() != IpAddress::Unknown)
{
    std::cout<<"Host Address: "<<ip_address.getHostAddress()<<std::endl;
    if (ip_address.getPortNumber() != 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Port Number: "<<ip_address.getPortNumber()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The header file of the class, IpAddress.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __IpAddress_H__
#define __IpAddress_H__


#include <string>

class IpAddress
{
public:
    enum Type
    {
        Unknown,
        IpV4,
        IpV6
    };
    ~IpAddress(void);

    /**
     * \brief   Gets the host address part of the IP address.
     * \author  Abi
     * \date    02/06/2010
     * \return  The host address part of the IP address.
    **/
    const std::string& getHostAddress() const;

    /**
     * \brief   Gets the port number part of the address if any.
     * \author  Abi
     * \date    02/06/2010
     * \return  The port number.
    **/
    unsigned short getPortNumber() const;

    /**
     * \brief   Gets the type of the IP address.
     * \author  Abi
     * \date    02/06/2010
     * \return  The type.
    **/
    IpAddress::Type getType() const;

    /**
     * \fn  static IpAddress Parse(const std::string& ip_address_str)
     *
     * \brief   Parses a given string to an IP address.
     * \author  Abi
     * \date    02/06/2010
     * \param   ip_address_str  The ip address string to be parsed.
     * \return  Returns the parsed IP address. If the IP address is
     *          invalid then the IpAddress instance returned will have its
     *          type set to IpAddress::Unknown
    **/
    static IpAddress Parse(const std::string& ip_address_str);

    /**
     * \brief   Converts the given type to string.
     * \author  Abi
     * \date    02/06/2010
     * \param   address_type    Type of the address to be converted to string.
     * \return  String form of the given address type.
    **/
    static std::string TypeToString(IpAddress::Type address_type);
private:
    IpAddress(void);

    Type m_type;
    std::string m_hostAddress;
    unsigned short m_portNumber;
};

#endif // __IpAddress_H__
```

The source file for the class, IpAddress.cpp

```
#include "IpAddress.h"
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

namespace bxp = boost::xpressive;

static const std::string RegExIpV4_IpFormatHost = "^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]+(\\:[0-9]{1,5})?$";
static const std::string RegExIpV4_StringHost = "^[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\:[0-9]+)?$";

IpAddress::IpAddress(void)
:m_type(Unknown)
,m_portNumber(0)
{
}

IpAddress::~IpAddress(void)
{
}

IpAddress IpAddress::Parse( const std::string& ip_address_str )
{
    IpAddress ipaddress;
    bxp::sregex ip_regex = bxp::sregex::compile(RegExIpV4_IpFormatHost);
    bxp::sregex str_regex = bxp::sregex::compile(RegExIpV4_StringHost);
    bxp::smatch match;
    if (bxp::regex_match(ip_address_str, match, ip_regex) || bxp::regex_match(ip_address_str, match, str_regex))
    {
        ipaddress.m_type = IpV4;
        // Anything before the last ':' (if any) is the host address
        std::string::size_type colon_index = ip_address_str.find_last_of(':');
        if (std::string::npos == colon_index)
        {
            ipaddress.m_portNumber = 0;
            ipaddress.m_hostAddress = ip_address_str;
        }else{
            ipaddress.m_hostAddress = ip_address_str.substr(0, colon_index);
            ipaddress.m_portNumber = atoi(ip_address_str.substr(colon_index+1).c_str());
        }
    }
    return ipaddress;
}

std::string IpAddress::TypeToString( Type address_type )
{
    std::string result = "Unknown";
    switch(address_type)
    {
    case IpV4:
        result = "IP Address Version 4";
        break;
    case IpV6:
        result = "IP Address Version 6";
        break;
    }
    return result;
}

const std::string& IpAddress::getHostAddress() const
{
    return m_hostAddress;
}

unsigned short IpAddress::getPortNumber() const
{
    return m_portNumber;
}

IpAddress::Type IpAddress::getType() const
{
    return m_type;
}
```

I have only set the rules for IPv4 because I don't know the proper format for IPv6. But I'm pretty sure it's not hard to implement it. Boost Xpressive is just a template based solution and hence do not require any .lib files to be compiled into your exe, which I believe makes is a plus.

By the way just to break down the format of regex in a nutshell...
**^** = start of string
**$** = end of string
**[]** = a group of letters or digits that can appear
**[0-9]** = any single-digit between 0 and 9
**[0-9]+** = one or more digits between 0 and 9
the '.' has a special meaning for regex but since our format has 1 dot in an ip-address format we need to specify that we want a '.' between digits by using '\.'. But since C++ needs an escape sequence for '\' we'll have to use "\\."
**?** = optional component

So, in short, **"^[0-9]+$"** represents a regex, which is true for an integer.
**"^[0-9]+\.$"** means an integer that ends with a '.'
**"^[0-9]+\.[0-9]?$"** is either an integer that ends with a '.' or a decimal.
For an integer or a real number, the regex would be **"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?$"**.
RegEx an integer that is between 2 and 3 numbers is **"^[0-9]{2,3}$"**.

Now to break down the format of the ip address:

```
"^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]+(\\:[0-9]{1,5})?$"
```

This is synonymous to: "^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]+(\:[0-9]{1,5})?$", which means:

```
[start of string][1-3 digits].[1-3 digits].[1-3 digits].[1-3 digits]<:[1-5 digits]>[end of string]
Where, [] are mandatory and <> are optional
```

The second RegEx is simpler than this. It's just a combination of a alpha-numeric value followed by an optional colon and port-number.

By the way, if you would like to test out RegEx you can use [this site](http://www.regextester.com/).

**Edit**: I failed to notice that you optionally had http instead of port number. For that you can change the expression to:

```
"^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]+(\\:([0-9]{1,5}|http|ftp|smtp))?$"
```

This accepts formats like:
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:3282
127.0.0.1:http
217.0.0.1:ftp
18.123.2.1:smtp

Comment: When people have a problem they say: I know, I'll use a regular expression. Now they have 2 problems.

Comment: LOL. It's not too hard to figure it out. I learned in less than 2 hours. It's not like he doesn't know the format and that he doesn't already have the solution. If I'm right, he already has a solution using std::stringstream and he wants an elegant solution.

I'll add a breakdown of regex in the post.

Comment: Bloated. Regular expressions have always worked just fine for me. Carping by all my lazy coworkers aside.

Comment: Bloated? You mean RegEx or the performance? If it is performance, maybe this might change your mind? http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/xpressive/doc/html/boost_xpressive/appendices/perf.html

Comment: Because it's 2021, added my take in X3. It does deal with the "ambiguous" cases gracefully as well. And throws in validation / DNS resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66827620/85371

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to the party, but I was googling for just how to do this. Spirit and C++ have grown up a lot, so let me add a 2021 take:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/oqjfbejcd)**

```
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>

auto parse_server_address(std::string_view address_spec,
                          std::string_view default_service = "https")
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    auto service = ':' >> +~char_(":") >> eoi;
    auto host    = '[' >> *~char_(']') >> ']' // e.g. for IPV6
        | raw[*("::" | (char_ - service))];

    std::tuple<std::string, std::string> result;
    parse(begin(address_spec), end(address_spec),
          expect[host >> (service | attr(default_service))], result);

    return result;
}

int main() {
    for (auto input : {
             "localhost",
             "localhost:11211",
             "127.0.0.1:http",
             "[::1]:11211",
             "::1", "[::1]",
             "::1:80", // Invalid: Is this the IPv6 address ::1:80 and a default
                       // port, or the IPv6 address ::1 and the port 80 ?
             "::1:http", // This is not ambigous, but for simplicity sake, let's
                         // consider this is forbidden as well.
         })
    {
        // auto [host, svc] = parse_server_address(input);
        fmt::print("'{}' -> {}\n", input, parse_server_address(input));
    }
}
```

Printing

```
'localhost' -> ("localhost", "https")
'localhost:11211' -> ("localhost", "11211")
'127.0.0.1:http' -> ("127.0.0.1", "http")
'[::1]:11211' -> ("::1", "11211")
'::1' -> ("::1", "https")
'[::1]' -> ("::1", "https")
'::1:80' -> ("::1", "80")
'::1:http' -> ("::1", "http")
```

### BONUS

Validating/resolving the addresses. The parsing is 100% unchanged, just using Asio to resolve the results, also validating them:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::asio::system_executor;
using boost::system::error_code;

int main() {
    tcp::resolver r(system_executor{});
    error_code    ec;

    for (auto input : {
             "localhost",
             "localhost:11211",
             "127.0.0.1:http",
             "[::1]:11211",
             "::1", "[::1]",
             "::1:80", // Invalid: Is this the IPv6 address ::1:80 and a default
                       // port, or the IPv6 address ::1 and the port 80 ?
             "::1:http", // This is not ambigous, but for simplicity sake, let's
                         // consider this is forbidden as well.
             "stackexchange.com",
             "unknown-host.xyz",
         })
    {
        auto [host, svc] = parse_server_address(input);

        for (auto&& endpoint : r.resolve({host, svc}, ec)) {
            std::cout << input << " -> " << endpoint.endpoint() << "\n";
        }

        if (ec.failed()) {
            std::cout << input << " -> unresolved: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints (limited network [Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LS43Vpfx9PfdUFP0) and Coliruhttp://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/497d8091b40c9f2d)

```
localhost -> 127.0.0.1:443
localhost:11211 -> 127.0.0.1:11211
127.0.0.1:http -> 127.0.0.1:80
[::1]:11211 -> [::1]:11211
::1 -> [::1]:443
[::1] -> [::1]:443
::1:80 -> [::1]:80
::1:http -> [::1]:80
stackexchange.com -> 151.101.129.69:443
stackexchange.com -> 151.101.1.69:443
stackexchange.com -> 151.101.65.69:443
stackexchange.com -> 151.101.193.69:443
unknown-host.xyz -> unresolved: Host not found (authoritative)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string host, port;
std::string example("[::1]:22");

if (example[0] == '[')
{
    std::string::iterator splitEnd =
        std::find(example.begin() + 1, example.end(), ']');
    host.assign(example.begin(), splitEnd);
    if (splitEnd != example.end()) splitEnd++;
    if (splitEnd != example.end() && *splitEnd == ':')
        port.assign(splitEnd, example.end());
}
else
{
    std::string::iterator splitPoint =
        std::find(example.rbegin(), example.rend(), ':').base();
    if (splitPoint == example.begin())
        host = example;
    else
    {
        host.assign(example.begin(), splitPoint);
        port.assign(splitPoint, example.end());
    }
}
```

Comment: In the IPV6 part, the `&&` on `splitEnd` condition seems dubious. You're invoking undefined behavior... and since we were looking for `]` I don't understand how the iterator could point to `:` to begin with.

Comment: I still don't understand how it could be ':', don't you mean (*(splitEnd++) == ':') ? (though there would be a risk of undefined behavior again).

Comment: I may appear... critical... but I am afraid you're still slightly off. Whenever you assign to port, you forget to increment the iterator, thus the first character of port will always be `:` if any. Is this intentional ?

Comment: @Matthieu M.: You are correct in that I completely botched the ipv6 addresses. But the ipv4 ones are correct. The `base()` member of reverse iterators is one element forward of that reverse iterator.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Boost.Spirit.Qi could handle this.

As mentioned, it's overkill (really).

```
const std::string line = /**/;

if (line.empty()) return;

std::string host, port;

if (line[0] == '[')           // IP V6 detected
{
  const size_t pos = line.find(']');
  if (pos == std::string::npos) return;  // Error handling ?
  host = line.substr(1, pos-1);
  port = line.substr(pos+2);
}
else if (std::count(line.begin(), line.end(), ':') > 1) // IP V6 without port
{
  host = line;
}
else                          // IP V4
{
  const size_t pos = line.find(':');
  host = line.substr(0, pos);
  if (pos != std::string::npos)
    port = line.substr(pos+1);
}
```

I really don't think this warrants a parsing library, it might not gain in readability because of the overloaded use of `:`.

Now my solution is certainly not flawless, one could for example wonder about its efficiency... but I really think it's sufficient, and at least you'll not lose the next maintainer, because from experience Qi expressions can be all but clear!

Comment: Thanks ! Probably not optimal, but definitely readable. However, what happens in case I supply the following string: `"[::1:22"` ?

Comment: `::1:22` would be considered the host: there is no error handling at all here, you could verify that in the first case, there is a closing bracket `assert(pos != std::string::npos)` or whatever you wish :)

Comment: does std::string have a function called count()? It gives me errors in VC2008.
error C2039: 'count' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'

Comment: I made a function to count the characters in a string and now it gives the wrong result with `"[::1:22"`. I got `Host = ::1:22` and `Port = ::1:22`.

Comment: @Vite: That should very likely have been `std::count(line.begin(),line.end(),':')`

Comment: Yea. But it still doesn't work. Mainly because it's not trying to eliminate any wrong versions of the 'address'.

Comment: `@Vite`: Good catch, that's because of there is an overflow of `pos`: `std::string::npos + 2 == 1`. Amusing. Anyway adding in the error handling (ie, stopping if no `]` is found) suppress the issue. Just need to do the same with the IPV4 part.

Comment: Because it's 2021, added my take in X3. It does deal with the "ambiguous" cases gracefully as well. And throws in validation / DNS resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66827620/85371

Comment: @sehe: Nice one. You've got a bit of an uphill battle to get your answer towards the top; let's hope others will throw in their votes too.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef ENDPOINT_HPP
#define ENDPOINT_HPP

#include <string>

using std::string;

struct Endpoint {
  string
    Host,
    Port;
  enum : char {
    V4,
    V6
  } Type = V4;
  __inline Endpoint(const string& text) {
    bind(text);
  }
private:
  void __fastcall bind(const string& text) {
    if (text.empty())
      return;
    auto host { text };
    string::size_type bias = 0;
    constexpr auto NONE = string::npos;
    while (true) {
      bias = host.find_first_of(" \n\r\t", bias);
      if (bias == NONE)
        break;
      host.erase(bias, 1);
    }
    if (host.empty())
      return;
    auto port { host };
    bias = host.find(']');
    if (bias != NONE) {
      host.erase(bias);
      const auto skip = text.find('[');
      if (skip == NONE)
        return;
      host.erase(0, skip + 1);
      Type = V6;
      ++bias;
    }
    else {
      bias = host.find(':');
      if (bias == NONE)
        port.clear();
      else {
        const auto next = bias + 1;
        if (host.length() == next)
          return;
        if (host[next] == ':') {
          port.clear();
          Type = V6;
        }
        else if (! bias)
          host.clear();
        else
          host.erase(bias);
      }
    }
    if (! port.empty())
      Port = port.erase(0, bias + 1);
    if (! host.empty())
      Host = host;
  }
};

#endif // ENDPOINT_HPP
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are getting the port and host via a string or in C++ an array of characters; you could get the length of the string. Do a for loop until the end of the string and go until you find a single colon by itself and the split the string into two parts at that location.

```
for (int i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
     if (string[i] == ':') {
          if (string[i+1] != ':') {
               if (i > 0) {
                    if (string[i-1] != ':') {
                         splitpoint = i;
}    }    }    }    }
```

Just a suggestion its kinda deep and I'm sure there is a more efficient way but hope this helps,
Gale

Comment: You know you can combine conditionals with `&&`? `if (string[i] == ':' && string[i+1] != ':' && i > 0 && string[i-1] != ':')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is even more *hacky* that what I came up to ;) And I'm not sure this handles the `IPv6` special cases.

Comment: @Michael - Yeah I know you can, however, if you try to do a comparison of string[i-1] at the same time you check if i>0 then you'll throw errors because you can't access string[-1] and I just threw it together =P

@ereOn - No problem just thought I'd give the first thing that popped in my mind

Comment: Also the `string[i+1]` when `i`'s value is `string.length() - 1` (last loop) resolves to `string[string.length()]` which I believe is out of bounds.

Comment: Oh... Yup didn't see that lol it would be out of bounds. See, told ya it could be better.

Comment: @GESchafer Doesn't short-circuiting handle (i >0) && (string[i-1] != ':') ?

Comment: @GESchafer You can do `if (0 && format_entire_harddrive());` and nothing will happen; [evaluation stops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) if the left side of an `&&` is false, without executing the right side