# How to parse rtsp url with boost qi?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to parse RTSP-url like this:

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
qi::int_parser<unsigned char, 16, 2, 2> hex_byte;

struct UrlParser : qi::grammar<stringIterator_t, UrlStruct()>
{
    UrlParser() : UrlParser::base_type(start)
    {
        using boost::spirit::int_;
        namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

        using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;
        
        // Parses http://, rtsp://, ftp://....
        protocol %= +(char_ - ':') >> "://"; 

        // Parsers for url decoding
        encodeChar.add("+", ' ');
        passwordRule = *((encodeChar | "%" >> hex_byte | char_) - '@');
        loginRule = *((encodeChar | "%" >> hex_byte | char_) - ':');

        // Parses user:pass@, user:@, :pass@
        credentials %= loginRule >> ':' >> passwordRule >> '@';

        // Parses host name or ip address in 192.168.0.1:80 192.168.0.1/script.cgi
        host %= +(!(char_("/") | (char_(":")) >> +ascii::digit >> (char_("/") | boost::spirit::eoi)) >> char_);

        // Parses port number in ":80", string
        port %= ':' >> int_;

        // Parses script path in "/video.cgi?resulution=1" string.
        path %= *(char_ - boost::spirit::eol);

        start %= -protocol
            >> -credentials
            >> host
            >> -port
            >> path
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<stringIterator_t, UrlStruct()>                 start;
    qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()>               protocol;
    qi::rule<stringIterator_t, UrlStruct::stringPair_t()>       credentials;
    qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()>               host;
    qi::rule<stringIterator_t, int()>                       port;
    qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()>               path;

private:
    qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()>               loginRule;
    qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()>               passwordRule;
    qi::symbols<char const, char const>                     encodeChar;

};
```

UrlStruct looks like this:

```
struct UrlStruct
{   
    typedef boost::optional<std::string>                    optString_t;
    typedef boost::optional<int>                            port_t;
    typedef boost::fusion::vector<std::string, std::string> stringPair_t;
    typedef boost::optional<stringPair_t>                   credentials_t;

    optString_t         protocol;

    credentials_t       credentials;

    std::string         host;

    port_t              port;

    std::string         path;
};
```

and this is work when I have url like this:

> rtsp://admin:admin@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

But when in my password I've '@' this is not working. URL for example:

> rtsp://admin:adm@in@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: It's good etiquette to make your question code self-contained. For example, `hex_byte` is missing, and a lot of people would have significant trouble figuring out how to make your code compile/invoke the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relatively obvious workaround would be to URL-escape the `@`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/387e34f8c1fcf031)**

```
UrlParser p;
for (std::string const input : {
        "rtsp://admin:admin@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov",
        "rtsp://admin:adm%40in@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov",
        "rtsp://admin:adm@in@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov",
        })
{
    stringIterator_t f = begin(input), l = end(input);
    Ast::UrlStruct u;
    if (parse(f, l, p, u)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << u << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
    }
```

Prints

```
Parsed: ( rtsp  (admin admin) wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net -- /vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov)
Parsed: ( rtsp  (admin adm@in) wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net -- /vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov)
Parsed: ( rtsp  (admin adm) in@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net -- /vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov)
```

As you can see the second (using `%40` for `@`) parsed fine.

### Fixing It The Flexible Way

Your host-rule already has some negative look-ahead assertions:

```
host = +(
    !(char_("/") | (char_(":")) >> +ascii::digit >> (char_("/") | boost::spirit::eoi))
    >> char_);
```

I'd simplify this to the equivalent:

```
host = +(~char_("/") - (port >> ('/' | qi::eoi)));
```

> *As an aside, I think the ":nnnn" is not a port unless it is at the very end of the hostname might be wrong and potentially unsafe. I suppose you have it there so you can still accept IPV6 addresses? See also [What is the nicest way to parse this in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958747/what-is-the-nicest-way-to-parse-this-in-c/66827620#66827620.)*

Similarly your `password` rule has a subtractive parser:

```
password = *((encodeChar | "%" >> hex_byte | char_) - '@');
```

What you want is close; you don't want to disallow `'@'` per se, but only if followed by a valid host production:

```
login    = *((encodeChar | "%" >> hex_byte | char_) - ':');
password = *((encodeChar | "%" >> hex_byte | char_) - 
        ('@' >> host >> eoh));
```

I introduced a nifty short-hand for `end-of-host`:

```
auto eoh = qi::copy('/' | qi::eoi);
```

This is to remove the repetition with the `host` rule. Note that now we finish the job by making sure `@` doesn't occur in the host-part (there are likely more characters to exclude according to the RFC, but this is the minimum to make your tests pass):

```
host = +(~char_("@/") - (portSpec >> eoh));
```

### Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2090a0b74a2906f9)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    struct UrlStruct {
        using optString_t = boost::optional<std::string>;
        using port_t      = boost::optional<int>;
        struct Credentials { // more natural, for ease of debug output really
            std::string login, password;
        };
        using credentials_t = boost::optional<Credentials>;

        optString_t   protocol;
        credentials_t credentials;
        std::string   host;
        port_t        port;
        std::string   path;
    };
    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::UrlStruct::Credentials, login, password)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::UrlStruct, protocol, credentials, host, port, path)
using stringIterator_t = std::string::const_iterator;

struct UrlParser : qi::grammar<stringIterator_t, Ast::UrlStruct()>
{
    UrlParser() : UrlParser::base_type(start)
    {
        namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

        using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;

        // Parses http://, rtsp://, ftp://....
        protocol = +(char_ - ':') >> "://"; 

        // Parsers for url decoding
        encodeChar.add("+", ' ');
        auto eoh = qi::copy('/' | qi::eoi);
        login    = *((encodeChar | "%" >> hex_byte | char_) - ':');
        password = *((encodeChar | "%" >> hex_byte | char_) - 
                ('@' >> host >> eoh));

        // Parses user:pass@, user:@, :pass@
        credentials = login >> ':' >> password >> '@';

        // Parses host name or ip address in 192.168.0.1:80 192.168.0.1/script.cgi
        host = +(~char_("@/") - (portSpec >> eoh));

        // Parses port number in ":80", string
        portSpec = ':' >> port_number;

        // Parses script path in "/video.cgi?resulution=1" string.
        path = *(char_ - qi::eol);

        start = -protocol
            >> -credentials
            >> host
            >> -portSpec
            >> path
            ;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(protocol)(credentials)(host)(portSpec)(
            path)(login)(password))
    }

private:
  qi::rule<stringIterator_t, Ast::UrlStruct()>              start;
  qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()>                 protocol;
  qi::rule<stringIterator_t, Ast::UrlStruct::Credentials()> credentials;
  qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()>                 host;
  qi::rule<stringIterator_t, int()>                         portSpec;
  qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()>                 path;

  qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()> login;
  qi::rule<stringIterator_t, std::string()> password;
  qi::symbols<char const, char const>       encodeChar;

  qi::uint_parser<uint8_t, 16, 2, 2> hex_byte;
  qi::uint_parser<uint16_t> port_number;
};

int main() {
    UrlParser p;
    for (std::string const input : {
            "rtsp://admin:admin@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov",
            "rtsp://admin:adm%40in@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov",
            "rtsp://admin:adm@in@wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov",
            })
    {
        stringIterator_t f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        Ast::UrlStruct u;
        if (parse(f, l, p, u)) {
            std::cout << "Yay: " << u << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Nay\n";

        }

        if (f != l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(f, l)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Now prints:

```
Yay: ( rtsp  (admin admin) wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net -- /vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov)
Yay: ( rtsp  (admin adm@in) wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net -- /vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov)
Yay: ( rtsp  (admin adm@in) wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net -- /vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov)
```

### Other Asides

- Port really should be limited to positive integers in the 16 bit range.
- Use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG to debug your grammar more easily
- don't use the implementation details (fusion::vector). Instead just `std::pair`, or indeed another adapted struct as I've done. That makes it much less painful to implement `operator<<` for quick debugging.
- You have a slight inconsistency regarding the end-of-input detection. In most places you use `eoi`, but then in `path` you accept until `eol`. You probably want to make things more consistent or decide what any input starting from the  `eol` means.
- Real life URI's sometimes contain login names but not the password (also without `:@`). I think your grammar might want to support that?
- A more structural deficiency with the parser right now is *efficiency*. All the negative look-aheads might lead to more back-tracking than desired. `- (':' >> port)` should be fine, but `- ('@' >> host)` might peek quite a few characters. Realistically, I donot think that should be a problem (unless of course you regularly have very long passwords with many ampersand characters).

  But on a serious note I'd take that as a sign the parser is trying to do too many things at the same level of abstraction. Things would be much easier if you divide-and-conquer: `schema://HOSTSTUFF/PATHSTUFF` first and then `HOSTSTUFF` in the way [I linked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958747/what-is-the-nicest-way-to-parse-this-in-c/66827620#66827620). Same then goes for the path/query part because there's a myriad of interesting things there that you really don't need to bother with when at first separating the toplevel limbs of the URI.