# Using '[' and ']' with boost::program_options

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am using boost `add_options()` like this way:

```
 ("setclient", po::value<std::string>(), "<awsipaddress>[:awsport[:mystring]] Change the settings.")
```

This works well if I use: `./mycli —setclient 192.68.1.1:8888:ui`

I want to allow special character like
`[` and `]`. The usage will be like

```
./mycli --setclient [192.68.1.1]:8888:ui
```

Try out:
I changed this

```
("setclient", po::value<std::string>(), "<awsipaddress>[:awsport[:mystring]] Change the settings.”)
```

to

```
("setclient", po::value<std::string>(), "<[awsipaddress]:>[:awsport[:mystring]] Change the settings.")
```

But doesn’t work for me

Mentioned in the problem statement my try out

Comment: Is it because `[` and `]` are treated special by your shell?

Comment: At least `—` is special, because that's U+2014

Comment: Not sure why the code begins with U+2028 before `("setclient"` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edited code is a descriptive text only, just intended to be printed as usage instructions. It doesn't encode a grammar or anything. So any changes to it don't matter.

The commenter has a good point that might get you half-way: the `[]` characters will often be special to the shell you're using. Wrap them in quotes e.g.:

```
./mycli --setclient '[192.68.1.1]:8888:ui'
```

or

```
./mycli --setclient "[192.68.1.1]:8888:ui"
```

Now, to actually **support** the additional characters you need to have a parser that expects the `[` and `]` characters added. If that's not yet the case, please update with a self-contained example (that correctly handles the old syntax) and we can tell you what is missing.

### Live Demo

With the simplest form:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9909d75a3781b10a)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    po::options_description desc;
    desc.add_options() //
        ("setclient", po::value<std::string>(),
         "<awsipaddress>[:awsport[:mystring]] Change the settings.") //
        ;                                                            //


    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

    std::cout << "Got: '" << vm["setclient"].as<std::string>() <<"'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
./a.out --setclient 192.68.1.1:8888:ui
Got: '192.68.1.1:8888:ui'
./a.out --setclient [192.68.1.1]:8888:ui
Got: '[192.68.1.1]:8888:ui'
```

### BONUS: Ipv6?

Guessing that you MIGHT require `[]` to allow ipv6 addresses (as they contain `:` characters), have a look at [What is the nicest way to parse this in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958747/what-is-the-nicest-way-to-parse-this-in-c/66827620#66827620), and a new live demo integrating that in your program-options:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f682368ba1571fc)**

```
#include <boost/asio/ip/address.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;
using boost::asio::ip::address;

struct Endpoint {
    address     address_;
    uint16_t    port_;
    std::string name_;

    static Endpoint parse_endpoint(std::string_view);
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    po::options_description desc;
    std::string setclient;
    desc.add_options() //
        ("setclient", po::value<std::string>(&setclient),
         "<awsipaddress>[:awsport[:mystring]] Change the settings.");

    po::variables_map vm;
    store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    notify(vm);

    auto ep = Endpoint::parse_endpoint(setclient);
    std::cout << std::left << "\t"
              << "Ip address: " << std::setw(12) << ep.address_ //
              << "Port: " << std::setw(12) << ep.port_          //
              << "Name: " << std::setw(12) << ep.name_          //
              << "\n";
}

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Endpoint, address_, port_, name_)

Endpoint Endpoint::parse_endpoint(std::string_view text) { //
    auto to_address = [](auto const& ctx) {
        auto& r   = _attr(ctx);
        _val(ctx) = address::from_string({r.begin(), r.end()});
    };

    auto octet = x3::uint8;
    auto ipv46 = x3::rule<void, address>{} = x3::raw[+~x3::char_("]")][to_address];
    auto ipv4                              = x3::rule<void, address>{} =
        x3::raw[octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet >> '.' >> octet][to_address];
    auto port  = (':' >> x3::uint16) | x3::attr(443);
    auto name  = (':' >> +x3::char_) | x3::attr(std::string("ui"));
    auto spec  = ('[' >> ipv46 >> ']' >> port >> name | //
                 ipv4 >> port >> name)                 //
        >> x3::eoi;

    Endpoint ep;
    parse(begin(text), end(text), x3::expect[spec], ep);
    return ep;
}
```

Printing for various test inputs:

```
+ ./a.out --setclient 192.68.1.1
    Ip address: 192.68.1.1  Port: 443         Name: ui          
+ ./a.out --setclient 192.68.1.1:backend
    Ip address: 192.68.1.1  Port: 443         Name: backend     
+ ./a.out --setclient 192.68.1.1:8443
    Ip address: 192.68.1.1  Port: 8443        Name: ui          
+ ./a.out --setclient 192.68.1.1:8443:backend
    Ip address: 192.68.1.1  Port: 8443        Name: backend     
+ ./a.out --setclient '[::1]'
    Ip address: ::1         Port: 443         Name: ui          
+ ./a.out --setclient '[::1]:backend'
    Ip address: ::1         Port: 443         Name: backend     
+ ./a.out --setclient '[::1]:8443'
    Ip address: ::1         Port: 8443        Name: ui          
+ ./a.out --setclient '[::1]:8443:backend'
    Ip address: ::1         Port: 8443        Name: backend     
+ ./a.out --setclient 127.0.0.1
    Ip address: 127.0.0.1   Port: 443         Name: ui          
+ ./a.out --setclient 127.0.0.1:backend
    Ip address: 127.0.0.1   Port: 443         Name: backend     
+ ./a.out --setclient 127.0.0.1:8443
    Ip address: 127.0.0.1   Port: 8443        Name: ui          
+ ./a.out --setclient 127.0.0.1:8443:backend
    Ip address: 127.0.0.1   Port: 8443        Name: backend
```

### BONUS 2: Converting Inside Program-Options

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be425cfbcb122236)**

```
struct Endpoint {
    address     address_;
    uint16_t    port_;
    std::string name_;

    static Endpoint parse_endpoint(std::string_view);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Endpoint const& ep) {
        return os << "[" << ep.address_ << "]:" << ep.port_ << ":" << ep.name_;
    }
    friend void validate(boost::any& value, std::vector<std::string> const& tt, Endpoint*, int) {
        if (tt.size() != 1)
            throw po::invalid_option_value("too many tokens");
        value = parse_endpoint(tt.front());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    po::options_description desc;

    Endpoint ep{boost::asio::ip::address_v4::loopback(), 443, "ui"};
    desc.add_options() //
        ("setclient", po::value<Endpoint>(&ep),
         "<awsipaddress>[:awsport[:mystring]] Change the settings.");

    po::variables_map vm;
    store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    notify(vm);

    std::cout << "\tparsed: " << ep << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Added a sefl-contained example showing that it works. This is using a bash shell on Coliru, so the `[]` do not require quoting there.

Comment: Added some bonus takes that illustrates the parsing steps to allow for ipv4/ipv6 addresses optionally `[]` braced