# URL parsing using boost::spirit

Tags: c++, url, boost-spirit, url-parsing

I’m experimenting with boost::spirit to write a URL parser. My objective is to parse the input URL (valid or invalid) and break it down into prefix, host and suffix as below:

Input ipv6 URL: https://[::ffff:192.168.1.1]:8080/path/to/resource
Break this into below parts:
Prefix: https://
Host: ::ffff:192.168.1.1
Suffix: :8080/path/to/resource

Input ipv6 URL: https://::ffff:192.168.1.1/path/to/resource
Break this into below parts:
Prefix: https://
Host: ::ffff:192.168.1.1
Suffix: /path/to/resource

Input ipv4 URL: https://192.168.1.1:8080/path/to/resource
Break this into below parts:
Prefix: https://
Host: 192.168.1.1
Suffix: :8080/path/to/resource

The colon character ‘:’ is used as delimiter in ipv6 address and also as delimiter for port in ipv4 address. Due to this ambiguity, I’m having hard time defining the boost::spirit grammar that works both for ipv4 and ipv6 URLs. Please refer the code below:

```
struct UrlParts
{
    std::string scheme;
    std::string host;
    std::string port;
    std::string path;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    UrlParts,
    (std::string, scheme)
    (std::string, host)
    (std::string, port)
    (std::string, path)
)

void parseUrl_BoostSpirit(const std::string &input, std::string &prefix, std::string &suffix, std::string &host)
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    // Define the grammar
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, UrlParts()> url = -(+qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9+-.") >> "://") >> -qi::lit('[') >> +qi::char_("a-fA-F0-9:.") >> -qi::lit(']') >> -(qi::lit(':') >> +qi::digit) >> *qi::char_;


    // Parse the input
    UrlParts parts;
    auto iter = input.begin();
    if (qi::parse(iter, input.end(), url, parts))
    {
        prefix = parts.scheme.empty() ? "" : parts.scheme + "://";
        host = parts.host;
        suffix = (parts.port.empty() ? "" : ":" + parts.port) + parts.path;
    }
    else
    {
        host = input;
    }
}
```

above code produces incorrect output for ipv4 URL as below:

Input URL ipv4: https://192.168.1.1:8080/path/to/resource
Broken parts:
Prefix: https://
Host: 192.168.1.1:8080
Suffix: /path/to/resource
i.e. Host is having :8080 instead of having it in Suffix.

If I change the URL grammar, I can fix the ipv4 but then ipv6 breaks.

Of-course this can be done using trivial if-else parsing logic, but I'm trying to do it more elegantly using boost::spirit. Any suggestions on how to update the grammar to support both ipv4 and ipv6 URLs ?

PS: I'm aware that URLs with ipv6 address w/o [ ] are invalid as per RFC, but the application I'm working on requires processing these invalid URLs as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In happy to look later when I have time. But for now are you aware of the Boost Url library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off your expression `char_("+-.")` accidentally allows for ',' inside the scheme: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14c00775d9f3d99e

To innoculate against that always put `-` first or last in character sets so it can't be misinterpreted as a range: `char_("+.-")`. Yeah, that's subtle.

`-'[' >> p >> -']'` allows for unmatched brackets. Instead say `('[' >> p >> ']' | p)`.

With those applied, let's rewrite the parser expression so we see what's happening:

```
// Define the grammar
auto scheme_ = qi::copy(+qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9+.-") >> "://");
auto host_   = qi::copy(+qi::char_("a-fA-F0-9:."));
auto port_   = qi::copy(':' >> +qi::digit);

qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, UrlParts()> const url =
    -scheme_ >> ('[' >> host_ >> ']' | host_) >> -port_ >> *qi::char_;
```

So I went on to create a test-bed to demonstrate your question examples:

> *Note I simplified the handling by adding `raw[]` to include `://` and just returning and printing `UrlParts` because it is more insightful to see what the parser does*

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef0800420eeb9f14)**

```cpp
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/pfr/io.hpp>

struct UrlParts { std::string scheme, host, port, path; };
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(UrlParts, scheme, host, port, path)

UrlParts parseUrl_BoostSpirit(std::string_view input) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    qi::rule<It, UrlParts()> url;
    //using R = qi::rule<It, std::string()>;
    //R scheme_, host_, port_;
    auto scheme_ = qi::copy(qi::raw[+qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9+.-") >> "://"]);
    auto host_   = qi::copy(+qi::char_("a-fA-F0-9:."));
    auto port_   = qi::copy(':' >> +qi::digit);
    url          = -scheme_ >> ('[' >> host_ >> ']' | host_) >> -port_ >> *qi::char_;

    // BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((scheme_)(host_)(port_)(url));
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((url));

    // Parse the input
    UrlParts parts;
    parse(input.begin(), input.end(), qi::eps > url > qi::eoi, parts);
    return parts;
}

int main() {
    using It        = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    using Exception = boost::spirit::qi::expectation_failure<It>;

    for (std::string_view input : {
             "https://[::ffff:192.168.1.1]:8080/path/to/resource",
             "https://::ffff:192.168.1.1/path/to/resource",
             "https://192.168.1.1:8080/path/to/resource",
         }) {
        try {
            auto parsed = parseUrl_BoostSpirit(input);
            // using boost::fusion::operator<<; // less clear output, without PFR
            // std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> " << parsed << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> " << boost::pfr::io(parsed) << std::endl;
        } catch (Exception const& e) {
            std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " EXPECTED " << e.what_ << " at "
                      << std::quoted(std::string_view(e.first, e.last)) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
"https://[::ffff:192.168.1.1]:8080/path/to/resource" -> {"https://", "::ffff:192.168.1.1", "8080", "/path/to/resource"}
"https://::ffff:192.168.1.1/path/to/resource" -> {"https://", "::ffff:192.168.1.1", "", "/path/to/resource"}
"https://192.168.1.1:8080/path/to/resource" -> {"https://", "192.168.1.1:8080", "", "/path/to/resource"}
```

### The Problem

You already assessed the problem: `:8080` matches the production for `host_`.  I'd reason that the port specification is the odd one out because it must be the last before `'/'` or the end of input. In other words:

```
auto port_   = qi::copy(':' >> +qi::digit >> &('/' || qi::eoi));
```

Now you can do a negative look-ahead assertion in your `host_` production to avoid eating port specifications:

```
auto host_   = qi::copy(+(qi::char_("a-fA-F0-9:.") - port_));
```

Now the output becomes

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/392dd8640e5f56d9)**

```
"https://[::ffff:192.168.1.1]:8080/path/to/resource" -> {"https://", "::ffff:192.168.1.1", "8080", "/path/to/resource"}
"https://::ffff:192.168.1.1/path/to/resource" -> {"https://", "::ffff:192.168.1.1", "", "/path/to/resource"}
"https://192.168.1.1:8080/path/to/resource" -> {"https://", "192.168.1.1", "8080", "/path/to/resource"}
```

Note that there are some inefficiencies and probably RFC violations in this implementation. Consider a static instance of the grammar. Also consider using X3.

### Using X3 and Asio

I have a related answer here: [What is the nicest way to parse this in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958747/what-is-the-nicest-way-to-parse-this-in-c/66827620#66827620). It shows an X3 approach with validation using Asio's networking primitives.

### Boost URL

Why roll your own?

```
UrlParts parseUrl(std::string_view input) {
    auto parsed = boost::urls::parse_uri(input).value();
    return {parsed.scheme(), parsed.host(), parsed.port(), std::string(parsed.encoded_resource())};
}
```

To be really pedantic and get the `://` as well:

```
UrlParts parseUrl(std::string_view input) {
    auto parsed = boost::urls::parse_uri(input).value();
    assert(parsed.has_authority());
    return {
        parsed.buffer().substr(0, parsed.authority().data() - input.data()),
        parsed.host(),
        parsed.port(),
        std::string(parsed.encoded_resource()),
    };
}
```

This parses what you have and much more (fragment from the [Reference Help Card](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/url/doc/html/url/ref/helpcard.html)):

[image]

The notable value is

- conformance (yes this means that IPV6 requires `[]`)
- proper encoding and decoding
- low allocation (many operations work exclusively on the source stringview)
- maintenance (you don't need to debug/audit it yourself)

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a56134474977c73f)**

```
==== "https://[::ffff:192.168.1.1]:8080/path/to/resource" ====
 Spirit -> {"https://", "::ffff:192.168.1.1", "8080", "/path/to/resource"}
 URL    -> {"https://", "[::ffff:192.168.1.1]", "8080", "/path/to/resource"}
==== "https://::ffff:192.168.1.1/path/to/resource" ====
 Spirit -> {"https://", "::ffff:192.168.1.1", "", "/path/to/resource"}
 URL    -> leftover [boost.url.grammar:4]
==== "https://192.168.1.1:8080/path/to/resource" ====
 Spirit -> {"https://", "192.168.1.1", "8080", "/path/to/resource"}
 URL    -> {"https://", "192.168.1.1", "8080", "/path/to/resource"}
==== "https://192.168.1.1:8080/s?quey=param&other=more%3Dcomplicated#bookmark" ====
 Spirit -> {"https://", "192.168.1.1", "8080", "/s?quey=param&other=more%3Dcomplicated#bookmark"}
 URL    -> {"https://", "192.168.1.1", "8080", "/s?quey=param&other=more%3Dcomplicated#bookmark"}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sehe. Your boost::spirit solution works for me. Can't use boost::url as that won't allow me processing ipv6 URLs without `[ ]`. Will check on static grammar instance and X3.

Comment: I've tried to write x3 equivalent here: https://onlinegdb.com/ckt_IuIQAe , but it gives this error:  

`
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/sequence.hpp:140:25: error: static assertion failed: Size of the passed attribute is less than expected.
  140 |             actual_size >= expected_size
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
`

Can you please suggest what am I missing ?  

PS: Unable to post the code here due to comment size limitation.

Comment: That code fits just fine in a new question :)